# Solve the equation about matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-equations

The equation is $x^2 = x$, which $x$ is a $2\times2$ matrix. Anyone can give me some hint? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the Jordan Normal Form is?

Comment: [Very much related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405225/number-of-solutions-x2-x).

Comment: @julien Thank you very much. That is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different hints:

1) This is a question with 2-by-2 matrices... why not just write down good ol' $x=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$, compute $x^2-x$, and see what happens?

2) You could also notice that for such a matrix $x$, we must have $x^2-x=0$; hence the minimal polynomial for $x$ must divide $t^2-t=t(t-1)$. What does that tell you about the matrix?

Comment: so the diagonal entries are 0 and 1, right?

Comment: Well, not necessarily.  There are two things here: first, such a matrix need not have both 0 and 1 as eigenvalues (for instance, the identity matrix only has 1 as an eigenvalue).  Second: if we know that the eigenvalues are distinct, all it tells us is that they will be on the diagonal (with 0's elsewhere) _after some change of basis_.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix satisfying this equation is, by definition, idempotent. A matrix will satisfy this equation if and only if it is idempotent. That is:

$$X^2=X$$

A $2\times{2}$ matrix is idempotent if and only if it is diagonalizable, and has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

In addition to the identity matrix $X=I_2$ and the zero matrix $X_2=O$, $X$ can therefore be constructed as follows, using any non-singular matrix $P$:

$$X=P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}P$$

or

$$X=P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}P$$

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: @nrpeterson Thanks, I always forget about the identity matrix.

Comment: One last thing: there's also the 0-matrix.

Comment: @nrpeterson Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

$x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ has single linear factors.

Consider the Jordan Normal Form. This shows that you can split the matrix up into single blocks with eigenvalues of 0 or 1.

Comment: Hi. I downvoted your answer although I value all your contributions in general. My reason is that the Jordan normal form is not relevant when a minimal polynomial splits with linear factors. I think you will agree that one should automatically think "diagonalization" in such a case.

Comment: @julien Yup, diagonlization should be the automatic conclusion. However, since OP didn't jump to that, I was trying to motivate the reason for it, which is the only reason why I didn't automatically say "This matrix is diagonalizable".